# Viewer Js Rotate Reload my image on Update Function

Tags: viewer

On Rotating image with custom rotate function and save the rotated picture in server. after the server responed i have update the viwerer with update function,bbut it cause reloading of image as orginal url is changed with new one, How can i stop reloading ?